# Integrating Gaussian white noise over a Gaussian density

Tags: normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, stochastic-processes, expected-value

I have encountered the following integral:
$$
\int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} X(\theta) \frac{\exp \big \{-\frac{\theta^2}{2\sigma^2} \big \}}{\sigma\sqrt{2 \pi}}d\theta
$$
where, for fixed $\theta = \theta_0$, $X(\theta_0) \sim N(0, 1)$. $X(\theta_1)$ and $X(\theta_2)$ are independent if $\theta_1 \neq \theta_2$. Hence $X(\theta)$ is Gaussian white noise indexed by $\theta$.

I am not sure about how to interpret this expression. In particular, by thinking about the integral as the limit of a sum:
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N X(\theta_i), \;\;\;\;\;\;\; X(\theta_i) \sim N(0, 1) \;\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;\;\; \theta_i \sim N(0, \sigma)
$$
for $i = 1, \dots, N$, I would say that it should converge to zero in probability, but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: Just to make sure, is $\exp \big \{\frac{\theta^2}{\sigma}\big\}$ correct?

Comment: @Alecos no, there is a typo, thanks for spotting it.

Comment: The "usual" $1/2$ is still missing, but I guess that's the way it should be here?

Comment: Yes I noticed, I should remove "attention to details" from my CV. :)

Answer (score 2):

We have by assumption, $Y = X(\theta) \sim N(0,1)$. As corrected, the integral is, by the so-called "law of the unconscious statistician",

$$ \int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} X(\theta) \frac{\exp \big \{-\frac{\theta^2}{2\sigma^2} \big \}}{\sigma\sqrt{2 \pi}}d\theta = \int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} X(\theta) f_{\theta}(\theta)d\theta =  E(X(\theta))=E(Y) = 0$$

**DISCUSSION**
Responding to @whuber 's comment, and pending clarification from the OP, I understand $X(\theta)$ as a function of $\theta$, which in turn, by the information in the question, is a $N(0,\sigma)$ random variable. Then the density of $\theta$ is 
$$f_{\theta}(\theta) = \frac{\exp \big \{-\frac{\theta^2}{2\sigma^2} \big \}}{\sigma\sqrt{2 \pi}}$$
and the result I give above is immediate -but I may have misunderstood the information provided in the question regarding the meaning of "indexing".

Comment: I am having trouble making sense of the first two inequalities and the notation. According to the question, $X$ is a family of *random variables* indexed by $\theta$: it is a *stochastic process*. Thus the integral is not a Riemann or Lebesgue integral at all and does not appear to be an expectation: it would have to be a random variable.  The meaning of $f_\theta(\theta)$ is mysterious. Could you please explain your interpretation, explain your notation, and justify your steps?

Comment: @whuber I added some discussion.

Comment: I am quite sure that Alecos final result is right: the integral is equal to zero. On the other hand, as Whuber is saying, $X(\theta)$ is a stochastic process not a random variable, so I'm not sure about writing $Y = X(\theta)$. I used the notation $X(\theta)$ to mean that for every $\theta$ on the real line there is a random variable. I used the expression "indexed by" to convey the fact that $X(\theta_1), X(\theta_2), \dots$ are iid.

Comment: So what you are describing by $X(\theta)$ is a stochastic process with continuous and random index?

Comment: Matteo, if you are sure the answer is zero, then some part of your description of $X$ must be incorrect. Could you supply a link or reference to where this integral appeared so we could have some context for understanding it?

Comment: Whuber, I was working on the sum ($\sum_{i=1}^NX(\theta_i)/N$) and I was interested in what happens when $N\to\infty$. I think that the sum has to converge to the expected value of $X(\theta)$, which is zero. I wanted to formalize this fact and I wrote down the integral, but maybe the limit of the sum doesn't correspond to the integral?

Comment: Alecos, yes that was my idea. The problem came about in a simulation: I simulate $\theta_i$ on the real line and I evaluate a function with noise $f(\theta_i) + X(\theta_i)$. I wanted to know what happens when the number of evaluations goes to infinity.

Comment: Matteo, that sum has little to do with the integral you wrote. Because you claim the $X(\theta)$ are independent, treating $\theta$ as a random variable accomplishes nothing at all. Moreover, $\theta$ clearly is *not* a random variable in your integral formulation. Could you show us where you encountered this integral?